# Can you have custom conditional exports in package.json?

Tags: node.js, import, package.json

I just learnt about [conditional-exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) and I was wondering if we can have other values than "node-addons", "node", "import", "require".

What I am tring to achieve:
A package.json with this structure:

```
"exports: {
....
 "./my-file.js": {
   "my-custom-rule": "./src/my-file-1.js",
   "default": "./src/my-file-2.js"
 },
...
}
```

So that my consumer package would have the following import:

```js
import "my-package/my-file.js;
```

This should import the file I want based on a custom env variable maybe or something else that makes this work.
Do you think this is possible ?

I managed to my own env variable, 'MY_VAR' but don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Depends on what you're relying on to _read_ that. Node.js only supports the documented conditions, other module loaders may vary.